# How to merge the completions of two completion-at-point-functions?

Tags: completion

In company-mode, you can merge completions by listing them together in a list. I would like to do a similar thing, where if I have two completion-at-list-functions setup, instead of trying one after the other, I'd like their candidates to get merged into one list.

Is that possible?

Comment: Ask this on the emacs help list: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-gnu-emacs

Comment: Or you can straight away file a feature request with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.